# PhoneGap - Jsonp Error 404 Not Found on call

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Here is a commun error, but every solution give on Stack didn't solve my problem.

I have a phonegap app, my jsonp call send me a 404 error

Here is the function of the controller (angularjs) :

```
$scope.pullContent = function() {
  $http.jsonp($scope.yourAPI+'/?page='+$scope.pageNumber+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert("### ERROR ###");
      alert(textStatus +' // '+ errorThrown);
      alert($scope.yourAPI+'?page='+$scope.pageNumber);
    }).success(function(response) {

    if($scope.pageNumber > response.pages){

      // hide the more news button
      $('#moreButton').fadeOut('fast');

    } else {

      $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(response.posts);
      window.localStorage.setObject('rootsPosts', $scope.items); // we save the posts in localStorage
      window.localStorage.setItem('rootsDate', new Date());
      window.localStorage.setItem("rootsLastPage", $scope.currentPage);
      window.localStorage.setItem("rootsTotalPages", response.pages);

      // For dev purposes you can remove the comment for the line below to check on the console the size of your JSON in local Storage
      // for(var x in localStorage)console.log(x+"="+((localStorage[x].length * 2)/1024/1024).toFixed(2)+" MB");

      $scope.totalPages = response.pages;
      $scope.isFetching = false;

      if($scope.pageNumber == response.pages){

        // hide the more news button
        $('#moreButton').fadeOut('fast');

      }

    }

  });

}
```

Here is my config.xml :

```
    <content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />

<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/android-icon-36x36.png"/>
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/android-icon-48x48.png"/>
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/android-icon-72x72.png"/>
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/android-icon-96x96.png"/>

<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/small.png"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/medium.png"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/large.png"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/xhdpi.png"/>
```

here is the result of "phonegap plugin list" :

```
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.5.4 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.14 "Network Information"
```

Can anybody have a solution for me ?

Comment: do you have a Content-Security-Policy meta tag in your index.html? if you have it, post it

Comment: @pk3 Have you posted your complete config.xml? I dont see following entries in your config.xml : <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

Comment: @p0k3 Did you tried out my above comment? Did it help?

Comment: @Gandhi -> Yes it solves the problem, thanks !

Comment: @p0k3 Posted the same in answer. Please accept if it was helpful so that it can be useful for others too. Also whats the procedure to attain the bounty as i m not aware of it? Please help me out

Comment: @Gandhi you should receive the award ;)

Comment: @p0k3 Thanks you so much. you made my day. Happy coding. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this config setting to your config.xml which should resolve the issue:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" /> 
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" /> 
<allow-intent href="tel:*" /> 
<allow-intent href="sms:*" /> 
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" /> 
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```